# How to create a payment form / pane directly from order_id

Tags: commerce

Study case : customers already have **the ability to pay only a deposit**. So they 'll have to come back and **pay the order balance later**.

How can I **create a payment form** ?

- where they will be able to directly submit a payment form and proceed to off-site payment to pay order balance
- without coming from cart/checkout process, (as it has already be done in deposit payment another day)

This will be linked from the user/%/orders/% page.

Is there any **commerce API function** that could fit that issue ?
I had a look at [`commerce_payment_order_transaction_add_form($form, &$form_state, $order`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!payment!includes!commerce_payment.forms.inc/function/commerce_payment_order_transaction_add_form/DC) but I could not find any doc to implement it, .

Thank you

PS : related issue: [Commerce partial payment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131182/commerce-partial-payment-pay-deposit-at-checkout-and-full-settlement-later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it doing the following :

with a link in `user/%/orders/%` page like `go_to_checkout/$order_id`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu();
 * Callback to pass order_id to checkout fn
 */
function commerce_partial_payment_menu() {

  $items['go_to_checkout'] = array(
    'title' => 'balance',
    'description' => 'Pay order balance',
    'page callback' => 'commerce_partial_payment_redirect_to_checkout',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' =>  TRUE,//still have to change that, maybe see own orders permission
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

/*
 * Prepare checkout process and redirects to checkout/%/review 
 */
function commerce_partial_payment_redirect_to_checkout($order_id) {

  $order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
  commerce_order_status_update($order, 'checkout_review', $skip_save = FALSE, $revision = TRUE, $log = '');

  drupal_goto('checkout/' . $order->order_id. '/review');
}
```